# MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery fails

Tags: c#, mysql, executenonquery

I am trying to execute an INSERT query in a mysql DB, but it doesn't happen anything except that the code executions stops and nothing gets inserted.
Here is the code (the connection is made at another point and is working):

```
            query = string.Format("INSERT INTO users (username, settings) VALUES('{0}', '{1}')", userName, sw.ToString());
            myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
            myCommand.CommandText = query;
            myCommand.Connection = con;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If I step the code, it stops after executenonquery, so obvisously something is wrong there. God I hate that it doesn't throw an error at me :(

Comment: It could be a lot of different things causing this to be honest. What is ExecuteNonQuery() returning?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't return anything, the code hangs after it is executed. The form is shown but things aren't working as they should etc.
I have tried executing the query directly against the db and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the connection is actually open and tried executing the method by assigning the result to an int in a try catch block.

```
int result;

try 
{
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();

    result = Convert.ToInt32(dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery());
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    logger.Error(ex);
 }
 finally
 {
     if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: amazing now it finally threw me an error and I were able to solve it! Thanks!

Comment: `int result` is never used, why do you have it there?